# Write a script to create users with pre-defined passwords

Tags: shell-script

I need a simple script.

One file named `userID` consists of 10 unixID and another file with name `passwd` consists of 10 password for those 10 unixID in file `userID`.
The first word of each file represents unixID and the corresponding passwd for that unixID.

I think it would need to execute two for loop or something to assign password for that specific userID

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use file [descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) to read the input from the two files in a single while loop execution.
Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assign file descriptors to users and passwords files
exec 3< users.txt
exec 4< passwords.txt

# Read user and password
while read iuser <&3 && read ipasswd <&4 ; do
    # Just print this for debugging
    printf "\tCreating user: %s with password: %s\n" $iuser $ipasswd
    # Create the user with adduser (you can add whichever option you like)
    adduser $iuser
    # Assign the password to the user, passwd must read it from stdin
    echo $ipasswd | passwd --stdin $iuser
done
```

Note how `passwd` is asked to read the password from `stdin`.
You may need to add lots of sanity checks to the above code, like checking if files exist, usernames doesn't have spaces, user doesn't already exist on system, etc ...
You can also extend the script to accept both file names as input arguments.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886683/read-stdin-bash-within-a-read-loop) on Stack overflow was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I were you, I would just make a csv of unixID,password, then

```
 while IFS=',' read -ra VARARRAY; do
     #The userid would be $VARARRAY[0] and passwd would be $VARARRAY[1]
     #Create user with distro's preferred method here.
 done
```

To run it and keep it dynamic I would

```
 cat newusers | ./createNewUsers.sh
```

Afterwards you could

```
 rm newusers
```

so that the passwords aren't lingering.

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash) helped a bit for creation of code.

Comment: No need to use an array. Quick and dirty example: `( echo 'hi1,hi2'; echo 'hi10,hi20' ) | while IFS=',' read USER PASSWD; do echo user = $USER pass = $PASSWD; done`